# Are custom Sharepoint Security Groups saved with a Sharepoint site temaplate

Tags: sharepoint

When a save a Sharepoint site that contains custom security groups as an stp file, does that stp file retain the groups?

Answer (score 1):

Can someone validate this:

I think this makes sense that the Sharepoint groups are not exported with the sts file.

The sts file represents a Site.
The Sharepoint groups are scoped at the Site Collection level.
Creating other sites within a Site Collection allows you to share the same security groups across the site collection.

Answer (score 0):

They will be include in the stp file, but i'm pretty sure they'll be broken if deployed to **another** site collection.

If you stay inside the same collection they'll continue to work. Security information is persisted in an stp.

P.S. I will vote to close this question, since it belongs on superuser.